# Use checkbox to set row as 'variable' then use button to format cell when pressed

Tags: excel

I have created a task manager sheet in Excel where column I to AD contain a series of steps that need to be performed for each job and starting at row 21 subsequent rows contain different jobs.

There is a separate Course management system that records details of each task within a job. I have created a button for each task which copies pre written text to the clipboard and allows me to update my course management system.

I plan to add option buttons to column a, and when selected that row becomes a variable. Then clicking the button will colour the cell accordingly.

I can get the option buttons to work, and I think I can get the cell formatting to work, what I can't work out is how to make the selected row a variable I can reference in the source i.e. make cell (I:'variable') Yellow when clicked.

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Using `Application.Caller` you can get the `TopLeftCell` of the option button.

```
Sub OptionBtn_Click()
    With ActiveSheet
        .Range("I" & .Shapes(Application.Caller).TopLeftCell.Row).Interior.Color = vbYellow
    End With
End Sub
```

If you have a lot of buttons to create it's probably easier to automate that.

```
Sub CreateOptionButtons()
    Dim lr As Long
    Dim pointsarr As Variant
    Dim grp As GroupBox
    Dim btn As OptionButton
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim startrow As Long
    Dim i As Long
    
    Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet1") 'Change to your sheet name
    startrow = 21 'Change as needed
    
    With ws
        lr = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
        pointsarr = getPoints(lr, startrow, 1, ws) 'Change as needed
        Set grp = .GroupBoxes.Add(pointsarr(0), pointsarr(1), pointsarr(2), pointsarr(3) + 3) 'the + 3 is so the last button is grouped
        
        For i = startrow To lr
            pointsarr = getPoints(i, i, 1, ws)
            Set btn = .OptionButtons.Add(pointsarr(0), pointsarr(1), pointsarr(2), pointsarr(3))
            With btn
                .OnAction = "Module1.OptionBtn_Click" 'Change as needed
                .Caption = "Row " & i 
                .Name = "OptionButton" & i
            End With
        Next i
    End With
End Sub

Function getPoints(lastrow As Long, start As Long, col As Long, ws As Worksheet) As Variant
    Dim left As Long
    Dim top As Long
    Dim width As Long
    Dim height As Long
    Dim returnarr(3) As Long
    
    With ws
        If col = 1 Then
            left = 1
        Else
            left = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(1, col - 1)).width
        End If
        
        If start = 1 Then
            top = 1
        Else
            top = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(start - 1, 1)).height
        End If
        
        width = .Columns(col).width
        
        height = .Range(.Cells(start, col), .Cells(lastrow, col)).height
        
    End With
    returnarr(0) = left
    returnarr(1) = top
    returnarr(2) = width
    returnarr(3) = height
    
    getPoints = returnarr()
        
End Function
```

You may need to play around with some of the values, the likely spots have comments next to them.